# No plot window in matplotlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I just installed matplotlib in Ubuntu 9.10 using the synaptic package system. 
However, when I try the following simple example

```
>>> from pylab import plot;
>>> plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x9aa78ec>]
```

I get no plot window. Any ideas on how to get the plot window to show?

Comment: pylab doesn't show the plot by default, since drawing and constant updating can be expensive.  You need to do an explicit `show()`.

Comment: Some official documentation on this issue: http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#matplotlib-compiled-fine-but-nothing-shows-up-when-i-use-it

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can type

```
import pylab
pylab.show()
```

or better, use `ipython -pylab`.

---

Since the use of `pylab` [is not recommended anymore](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/index.html#the-pylab-api-disapproved), the solution would nowadays be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 39):

`pylab.show()` works but blocks (you need to close the window).

A much more convenient solution is to do `pylab.ion()` (interactive mode on) when you start: all (the pylab equivalents of) `pyplot.*` commands display their plot immediately. [More information on the interactive mode](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode) can be found on the official web site.

I also second using the even more convenient `ipython -pylab` (`--pylab`, in newer versions), which allows you to skip the `from … import …` part (`%pylab` works, too, in newer IPython versions).

Comment: but you need to call `pylab.show()` first to even open a figure.

Comment: @Steve: my experience is that this strongly depends on the backend.  On Mac OS X with the regular Python shell, I don't have to do show() (or draw(), for that matter): plot() opens a new window.

Comment: Ah, okay. Good point. I only have experience with ipython in Linux.

Comment: draw() doesn't work for me, but pylab.ion() works. I'm using OSx

Comment: Same thing here in the Python shell with the latest Matplotlib. I updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

BEFORE import pylab

Answer (score 11):

The code snippet below works on both Eclipse and the Python shell:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Come up with x and y
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

# Just print x and y for fun
print x
print y

# Plot the x and y and you are supposed to see a sine curve
plt.plot(x, y)

# Without the line below, the figure won't show
plt.show()
```

Comment: As many other answers clarify, this may work for you at the moment, but it all depends on how your matplotlib backend is configured.

Answer (score 10):

Any errors show up? This might an issue of not having set the backend. You can set it from the Python interpreter or from a config file (`.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`) in you home directory.

To set the backend in code you can do

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

where 'Agg' is the name of the backend. Which backends are present depend on your installation and OS.

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#backends

http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: Totally works, thanks. To be clear, the simplest thing to do (once you konw this is working of course) is to set your backend in `.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` to `backend: Agg`. Then you don't have to explicitly `use` one every time :)

Answer (score 2):

Modern IPython uses the "`--matplotlib`" argument with an optional backend parameter. It defaults to "auto", which is usually good enough on Mac and Windows. I haven't tested it on Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution, but I would expect it to work.

```
ipython --matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter an issue in which `pylab.show()` freezes the IPython window (this may be Mac OS X specific; not sure), you can cmd-c in the IPython window, switch to the plot window, and it will break out.

Apparently, future calls to `pylab.show()` will not freeze the IPython window, only the first call. Unfortunately, I've found that the behavior of the plot window / interactions with show() changes every time I reinstall matplotlib, so this solution may not always hold.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting IPython with the `--pylab` option, you shouldn't need to call `show()` or `draw()`. Try this:

```
ipython  --pylab=inline
```

Answer (score 0):

`--pylab` no longer works for [Jupyter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter), but fortunately we can add a tweak in the `ipython_config.py` file to get both `pylab` as well as  `autoreload` functionalities.

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload', 'pylab']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2', '%pylab']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are user of Anaconda and Spyder then best solution for you is that :

Tools
-->
Preferences
-->
Ipython console
-->
Graphic Section

Then in the **Support for graphics (Matplotlib)** section:

select two avaliable options

and in the **Graphics Backend**:

select **Automatic**

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

plt.plot(y)

pylab.show(block=False)

plt.pause(3) #After 3 seconds the plot closes.
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

%matplotlib inline

use this line whenever your plot with any library hides in the backend of jupyter notebook.

This works fine for me.

Answer (score -5):

Another possibility when using easy_install is that you need to require the most recent version of matplotlib.
Try:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("matplotlib")
```

before you import matplotlib or any of its modules.

Comment: This just makes sure `matplotlib` is installed, not affect how the window handling is done.