# module getting stuck on show() in ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, show, freeze

Hello I created a module in the ipython text editor and then called it in the ipython notebook and it freezes when I call show() from matplotlib. I am running on a surface pro windows 10. I have checked for answers and I found that using import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')

in the beginning of my module worked the first time and then every time I tried to run after it has killed my kernel. Here is my module which is called Take_Home.py:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import pdb
#mpl.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml

def statistics(array,bin_size):

    #calculate mean and standard deviation of array
    mean=np.mean(array)
    std=np.std(array)

    #get the gaussian fit of the data
    gaussian=ml.normpdf(array,mean,std)

    #plot the normalized histogram
    plt.hist(array,bins=np.arange(np.min(array), np.max(array) + bin_size,  bin_size),normed=True)

    #plot the gaussian function over the histogram
    plt.plot(array,gaussian,'.k')

    #this attempts to show the plot but doesn't work
    plt.show()

    #saves the plot to a PDF
    plt.savefig('Statistics.pdf')
```

and here is the ipython notebook that calls the module:

```
import Take_Home as th
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#initialize an array of 1000 elements and set them all to 1
rd=np.arange(0,1000)
rd[:]=1

#change the array to have all random numbers with a std of 2 and a mean of 1
rd=rd*(2*np.random.randn(1,1000)+1)

#transpose it because the error message said so
rd=np.transpose(rd)

#declare bin size
binsize=0.2

#use method inside module
th.statistics(rd,binsize)
```

I just need to show the plot and I don't know why it's working any help would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: It works fine on my machine (win10), latest Ipython/Jupyter (i'm not calling the separate file, just put everything into one cell). The graph window pops up, maybe you are hiding it.  Or try to show it inline like `%matplotlib inline`. 2nd step: it also works when I import `Take_Home.py`, note that capitalization in the name matters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

So my teacher wants us to use modules which would make us put it in a text file and then call it in a notebook. 

I tried to put the .py extension but I got this error message: 

    ImportError: No module named 'Take_Home.py'; 'Take_Home' is not a package

Comment: Maybe try updating your install if it's older, very easy if you use `Anaconda`, just `conda update jupyter` etc.

Comment: yeah I updates everything as well :(

Comment: Is there an error message? Or just no window? What about the inline graphics, i.e. add the line `%matplotlib inline` after your imports.

Comment: Yeah when I try to put the inline command in the module it gives me an error saying invalid syntax on the inline call

Comment: Maybe it's how you call ipython in your cmd line. Check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130913/no-plot-window-in-matplotlib. Also, make yourself the most simple example possible for a plot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274351/how-does-one-set-keyword-block-in-plt-show-equal-to-true-by-default/36275243#36275243 for some explanation of what `plt.show` does